# Правильно ли я делаю, закрытие блока, JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

Начал знакомство с JS. Мне необходимо закрывать блок по клику на крестик. В блоке (`<div>`) есть `button` с `background` в виде крестика, на нем событие `onclick="closeBlock(cityBlock);"`, в качестве аргумента/параметра передается элемент/`id` блока который надо закрыть. Код функции :

```
    function closeBlock(block)
    {
        var container = $("#" + block.id);
        container.slideToggle("slow");
    }
```

Функцию я не захотел делать так `var container = $("#cityBlock");` потому что подумал, что эту функцию, в будущем может понадобится вызывать и в другим местах на закрытие блоков с другими `id`. Все работает, но мне почему то кажется что так делать не правильно, именно вот этот кусок  `$("#" + block.id);`, или все нормально и так писать допустимо?

Comment: вместо `$("#" + block.id);` лучше `$(block);`

Answer (score 0):

С помощью `jQuery` можно сделать так:

```js
$(".event-btn").click(function() {
  $(this).parent().find(".toggleElement").toggleClass("hidden");
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="toggle-block">Block 1 <a href="#" class="event-btn">Click</a> <span class="toggleElement hidden">123</span></div>
<div class="toggle-block">Block 2 <a href="#" class="event-btn">Click</a> <span class="toggleElement hidden">123</span></div>
<div class="toggle-block">Block 3 <a href="#" class="event-btn">Click</a> <span class="toggleElement hidden">123</span></div>
<div class="toggle-block">Block 4 <a href="#" class="event-btn">Click</a> <span class="toggleElement hidden">123</span></div>
<div class="toggle-block">Block 5 <a href="#" class="event-btn">Click</a> <span class="toggleElement hidden">123</span></div>
<div class="toggle-block">Block 6 <a href="#" class="event-btn">Click</a> <span class="toggleElement hidden">123</span></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

То что вы написали можно проделать и без использования jQuery

```js
function myCloseFunction(id) {
  document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none';
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div id="div1">1-й вариант без исп. вспомогательной функции и адресацией по id<button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('div1').style.display='none';">Close</button></div>
  <div id="div2">1-й вариант с исп. вспомогательной функции и адресацией по id<button type="button" onclick="myCloseFunction('div2')">Close</button></div>
  <div id="div3">2-й Предпочтительный вариант без привязки к id (предполагается что кнопка в этом случае ребенок первого уровня)<button type="button" onclick="parentElement.style.display='none';">Close</button></div>
</div>
```

Ясное дело что так топорно никто в реальности уже давно не делает, но вдруг надо именно такое поведение